# Lucene searchAfter returns same results as previous query

Tags: java, lucene

I just discovered that *Lucene* supports paging using the `searchAfter` method, so I added it to my implementation. Unfortunately it returns the same results as the previous query and I don't get why.

Basically what I'm doing is calling my `search` method and storing both the `Query` and the last `ScoreDoc` returned by `collector.topDocs()`. Then, when the user wants to load the next page, I call `searcher.searchAfter(previousResult, previousQuery, MAX_HITS)` but I receive the same results that I would receive by running `searcher.search(query, collector)`.

Please note that I'm returning 15 documents per page and my query has 32 hits, so I'd expect it to have at least 2 pages.

Here's the code:

```
private Query previousQuery;
private ScoreDoc previousResult;
private float previousMaxScore;

private ScoreDoc[] search(String query) throws ParseException, IOException {
    Query q = parser.parse(query);
    TopScoreDocCollector collector = TopScoreDocCollector.create(MAX_HITS_PER_PAGE);
    searcher.search(q, collector);
    TopDocs result = collector.topDocs();
    // Let's normalize scores
    for (ScoreDoc scoreDoc : result.scoreDocs) {
        scoreDoc.score /= result.getMaxScore();
    }
    // If the query had some results then we save the last one to support paging
    if (collector.getTotalHits() > 0) {
        previousQuery = q;
        previousResult = result.scoreDocs[result.scoreDocs.length - 1];
        previousMaxScore = result.getMaxScore();
    }        
    return result.scoreDocs;
}

private ScoreDoc[] searchNextPage() throws IOException {
    // previosuResult is CORRECT, it's the last one from the previous query so it's not part of the issue.
    TopDocs result = searcher.searchAfter(previousResult, previousQuery, MAX_HITS_PER_PAGE);        
    // Let's normalize scores        
    for (ScoreDoc scoreDoc : result.scoreDocs) {
        scoreDoc.score /= previousMaxScore;            
    }
    // Let's update previous result with the new one
    if (result.scoreDocs.length > 0) {
        previousResult = result.scoreDocs[result.scoreDocs.length - 1];
    }        
    return result.scoreDocs;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?